# XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX ignore \hyphenation

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyphenation

I'm trying to get all hyphenations that the LaTeX-algorithm gives out. So I'm trying this:

```
echo "\\\documentclass{standalone}
\\\hyphenation{Py-ra-mi-de}
\\\showhyphens{Pyramide}" | xelatex
```

This does not give me any errors, so that the output contains

```
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Py-ra-mide
```

which I can parse for. But the hyphenation that it gives me is not Py-ra-mi-de, but Py-ra-mide. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: so from the answer in summary you would need `echo "\documentclass{standalone} \begin{document} \hyphenation{Py-ra-mi-de} \righthyphenmin2 \showhyphens{Pyramide} \end{document}" | XeLaTeX` and get a result of .pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default language (American English) sets `\lefthyphenmin=2` and `\righthyphenmin=3`. Thus no TeX engine will hyphenate past the `m`, whatever hyphenation points you define.

If you try

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\hyphenation{Py-ra-mi-de}

\showhyphens{Pyramide}

\selectlanguage{italian}

\hyphenation{Py-ra-mi-de}

\showhyphens{Pyramide}

\end{document}
```

you get

```latex
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--8
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Py-ra-mide

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--14
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Py-ra-mi-de
```

It wouldn't be necessary to set the hyphenation points again, actually, because the hyphenation you want fits into the patterns for Italian. The settings for this language have `\lefthyphenmin=2` and `\righthyphenmin=2`.

Answer (score 8):

You must set the hyphenmins correctly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\hyphenation{Py-ra-mi-de}


\begin{document}
\showhyphens{Pyramide}

\righthyphenmin1
\lefthyphenmin1

\showhyphens{Pyramide}

\end{document}
```

The first \showhyphens gives your output but the second now

```
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Py-ra-mi-de
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This solves my problem. What do \righthyphenmin and \lefthyphenmin exactly do?

Comment: They set the number of minimal chars left and right of a hyphenation.